# Get values for tags of Opentracing span

Tags: opentracing

I am using a `io.opentracing.Span` to add tracing to a service.

Inside one of the more nested functions, I want to access information that has already been added to the span using `span.setTag(key:String, value:String)` by the rest of the setup. When debugging one test case, I can see the span's `tags` attribute, which contains all infos I require.

So far I have looked for functions and attributes that `Span` provides, but have found nothing that allows me read access to those `tags` values.
Is there a way to get tag values?

Answer (score 0):

The Span is an interface and it does not include getting the tags unfortunately (I also wanted to check they are set correctly elsewhere in the code).

I saw in my case the implementation was an OTSpan (from Open Tracing) but I couldn't cast to it.

The only solution I could think of so far was to enumerate the fields of the implementation object with reflection and read the respective field value (don't forget to allow access to a private field). The exact field name could vary between implementations.